# XML vs json with complicated data

Tags: xml, json

I am currently writing an API for my site so that a client program can easily access data. Currently, for simple functions, such as metadata and search, I am using JSON, as it is compact and suits my needs since the data is relatively simple.

However, one of the primary functions is retrieving certain data that is complicated and nested. Should use JSON, since it is lightweight, or XML, because it seems to be more suitable for complicated nesting of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some other questions to consider that would favor use of XML:

*Do you need complex validation rules?* XML Schema is more mature than anything I've seen with JSON, and there are lots of features like substitutionGroups and complexTypes that you can use to enforce a very specific structure.

*Will namespaces benefit you?* For example, will you have data elements/attributes with the same names but different meanings within the same document? If so, namespaces are useful for disambiguation. They're also useful when you need to blend in other XML-structured data (XHTML, SOAP, what have you) with your own data.

*Do you need to support mixed content?* I'm not sure how this could be expressed easily in JSON:

```
<message>I have <value>17</value> widgets</message>
```

*Does encoding information need to be self contained within the document?* In XML you can specify the encoding as part of the document. With JSON, this information is presumed or external to the document itself (HTTP headers).

If the answer is "no" to these questions, you're probably safe off with JSON.

Comment: The validation rules don't need to be that complex and I don't need mixed content, but it would be nice to have encoding information embedded in the data, as well as external namespaces since I eventually want to make this a public API. Thanks!